# Using numpy where on multidimensional array but need to control indexing

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I need to modify elements of an 3D array if they exceed some threshold value.  The modification is based upon related elements of another array.  More concretely:

```
A_ijk = A_ijk if A_ijk < threshold value

= (B_(i-1)jk + B_ijk) / 2, otherwise
```

Numpy.where provides most of the functionality I need, but I don't know how to iterate over the first index without an explicit loop.  The follow code does what I want, but uses a loop.  Is there a better way?  Assume A and B are same shape.

```
for i in xrange(A.shape[0]):
    A[i] = numpy.where(A[i] <= threshold, A[i], (B[i - 1] + B[i]) / 2)
```

To address the comments below: The first few rows of A are guaranteed to be below threshold.  This keeps the i index from looping over to the last entry of A.

Comment: Does this wrap around? So for example if `i == 0`, then B[i-1] should reference the last row of the array?

Comment: `A` and `B` can't be of the same shape if `A[i,...]` references both `B[i,...]` and `B[i-1,...]`. I mean it can, but are you sure the loopy code does what you want it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vectorize your operation by using boolean indexing to replace the elements of `A` that are above the threshold. A little care has to be taken, since the auxiliary array corresponding to `(B[i-1] + B[i])/2` has one less size along the first dimension than `A`, so we have to explicitly ignore the first row of `A` (knowing that they are all below the threshold, as explained in the question):

```
import numpy as np

# some dummy data
A = np.random.rand(3,4,5)
B = np.random.rand(3,4,5)
threshold = 0.5
A[0,:] *= threshold # put the first dummy row below threshhold
mask = A[1:] > threshold # to be overwritten, shape (2,4,5)

replace = (B[:-1] + B[1:])/2 # to overwrite elements in A from, shape (2,4,5)

# replace corresponding elements where `mask` is True
A[1:][mask] = replace[mask]
```

Comment: Thanks! This will work.  As mentioned above, the first row of A is known to be below threshold, so the mask values from the B matrix never "loop around"

Comment: @JimParker thanks, I missed that detail (I had already begun writing up the answer by then). I updated the answer, it's slightly simpler with this additional assumption (no auxiliary array is needed).

Answer (score 0):

You can use where to directly index into ndarray:

```
a   = np.random.rand(4,3,10)
b   = np.zeros(a.shape)
idx = np.where(a < .1)
print(a)
a[idx] = b[idx]
print(a)
```

If a for-loop is needed however, just convert the ravel the indices and update.

```
a   = np.random.rand(4,3,10)
b   = np.zeros(a.shape)
idx = [np.ravel_multi_index(i, a.shape) for i in zip(*np.where(a < .1))]
print(a, idx)
for i in idx:
    a.ravel()[i] = b.ravel()[i]
print(a)
```